# Terminology: Screen with both filter and sort actions

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design

What would be a proper way of calling a screen that provides both filter and sort actions? Focus is on Android apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We call it **Refine** in our job search Android app (Naukri.com), So does [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-and-filter-data-for-a-mail-merge-af9f7912-5e1d-40a6-a52a-f41eccf98b8e) and ebay in its [iOS app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_R3eSFcML0). You can add a suffix like **Refine results** or **Refine *[list items]***.

Another option could be call it **Filter** (specially if you are using a funnel icon) and add a Sort section on top.

Answer (score 0):

I will need some more context in order to give a better answer. I guess that you have something like a product-list page, or an array of elements.

Possible names that I would use:

- "Refine your data"
- "Refind your products" => When it comes to a product-list page
- "Options"
- "Filters & Sorting" => It might be better to have a list of filters and a list of sorting ways. Keep in mind that users might not truly understand the difference. Also, a lot of times, sorting happens in the main screen and filters in another screen, especially when it come to mobile.

Comment: This is an entertainment app with mainly image content. I was thinking options but we have a snackbar which reminds users that sorting or filtering have been applied. I could not come up with good text for the snackbar. It would be best if it would just say "Filters applied" and then have a Reset-button.

Comment: "Filters applied" would be a good option if filters are applied. So it could be "Filters" and "Filters applied". Also reset-button sounds good. I am wondering if it is possible on your screen to show already which filters are applied, so that the user doesn't need to go to the other screen a lot of times.

Comment: I'm just worried that can it be misleading if the "Filters" screen has sorting options also? Or maybe I'm just overthinking it. :)

Comment: My suggestion is to have Sorting on the main screen. For example look at e-commerce apps. They have a separate Filter page and the Sorting happens in the product-list page. Of course it depends on the Sorting possibilities that you would like to include.

Answer (score 0):

This screen from Expedia seems to show a good option for combining both filter and sort on one screen (though it is iOS and not Android).
The filters button and search bar only appears after the user pulls the list "down", indicating that they scrolled through the list and were not satisfied with the results.

[image: app list screen]

The Expedia iOS app has some really excellent UX in my opinion.